# How to know if the php zip extension already install? How to recompile PHP in Linux also?

Tags: php, zip

I already have LAMP installed. How do I recompile PHP to enable zip extension?

Also, where is the PHP configuration file located?

Comment: check with phpinfo(), pretty certain it's already there.

Comment: `if (!extension_loaded('zip')) { echo 'zipless' }`

Comment: execute in command line:
'php -m'
and check if your 'zip' extension is in the list

Answer (score 5):

This completey depends on the distro of linux and how you installed your stack. If you run `php --ini` from the command line it will let you know the various dirs for `.ini` files.

Comment: php --ini | grep zip

Answer (score 0):

The PHP config file should be somewhere in:
/usr/local/apache/php or /usr/local/apache2/php